# Cloning/replicating/copying dashboard admin settings

Tags: theme-options, dashboard, clone-site

I have a local multi-site installation for my different client projects. For a given project, I need to have the same theme installed locally as the online site's theme. But I also need the same custom menus, theme options, widgets, etc: all dashboard/admin settings. Otherwise I often end up with a very different looking site locally which doesn't allow me to work in good conditions, especially for front-end tweaking work.

What is the best way to deal with this problem? Is it to abandon the multi-site idea altogether and instead to clone (DB + files) every single client website from scratch?

Comment: You want all "settings" (alias: DB content) locally, but your question states "cloning dashboard admin settings" and then talking about dropping multisite vs. cloning database + files... Please rework your question, add a clear title that describes your content and add some proper tags. After 74 questions we expect you to know the basics.

Comment: "Dashboard" just is a very minor part of your "settings"/database `{$wpdb->prefix}options` table. Making it such prominent in title is quite confusing. If you want to have everything that is definable somewhere, then you'll need to have users + user meta data as well. Summed up, you want to know how to migrate a database from Server to local server, right?

Comment: Based on what you say, I guess this is the only way to get all theme option settings, widgets, custom menus and so on, replicated locally from remote server. So there's no other solution that cloning files and DB, and I suppose a multi-site installation doesn't allow that.

Comment: Drake, please take a look at the WP database scheme in Codex. Take a look at what _exactly_ the import/export plugins do. In other words: Please do some research at what exactly you want to do.